# Fill out a form on click?

Tags: javascript, forms, autofill

What would be the best way to fill out a form on an html page when someone clicks a link.

The best example i can think of is on *chan sites, where a user clicks on the ID of a comment and that ID is then inserted into the comment Text Area.

Comment: Define "best way." Are you just looking for Javascript to do this?

Comment: well to the best of my knoweldge i would say Javascript, but if there is something better i dont want to limit myself

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use JavaScript to intercept the click and then copy the data.